# iCloud email adding extra character to each line

Tags: icloud, email

I have an auto response to direct iCloud emails to my preferred address.
The message being sent is having an 'r' added to the end of each line like so (except the last line....):

Hi-r
In the future please use my main email address:r

Name@mydomain.comr

This email has been forwarded on to that address automatically.r

Thanks!r

Joe

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question....

I went into iCloud and saw that sometime recently it had added a \r (translating a return??) to each line of my auto reply.

Deleted that and all is well.